# Feed user input directly into an int array PYTHON

Tags: python, input

right, one thing i couldnt find about is feeding input directly into an int array

i've tried

```
inp = raw_input("Enter input").split(",")
```

doesn't do much but to print a single string without any separation

advice very welcomed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
inp = raw_input('Enter input: ')
ints = map(int, inp.split(','))
```

#### Example

```
>>> inp = raw_input('Enter input: ')
Enter input: 5,4,3,2,1
>>> map(int, inp.split(','))
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```